# Ansible How to specify groups on the command line to run the corresponding tasks

Tags: ansible

ansible inventory

```
# hosts
[groupA]
192.168.1.1

[groupB]
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.3
```

ansible tasks:

```
# site.yml
---
- name: test
  hosts: all
  tasks:
   - name: taskA
     command: echo testA
     when: "'groupA' in group_names "

   - name: taskB
     command: echo testB
     when: "'groupB' in group_names "
```

I want to perform the task of `taskA` through `groupA`, how to do it?I use the following command to execute

```
ansible-playbook site.yml -l groupA -i hosts
```

However, getting the following result is not what I want because it also executes `taskB`, but I only want to use `groupA` to execute `taskA`.

I don't want to use `ansible tag` because I have a lot `roles`, there will be a lot of work to add each `tag` to each `role`.

```
PLAY [test]  *******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts]  ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.1]

TASK [taskA]  ******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.1]

TASK [taskB]  ******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.1]

PLAY RECAP  ********************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.1.1              : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Q "`I just want the machine inside group_B to execute Task of B...For example, the machine inside group_B only executes Task of B.`"

A: Test the membership of the hosts in the groups. See the code below.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Task of group_A
    command: bash groupA.sh
    when: inventory_hostname in groups['group_A']
  - name: Task of group_B
    command: bash groupB.sh
    when: inventory_hostname in groups['group_B']
```

Q: "`I just want to run Task of group_B. What should my order be? ansible-playbook site.yml -l group_B -i ansible_inventory If group_A and group_B have a common ip, Task of group_A will be executed, but I only want to execute Task of group_B.`"

"`I don't want to use ansible tag because I have a lot. roles, there will be a lot of work to add each tag to each role.`"

A: Use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role)  and apply tags (added in 2.7). Such applied tags are inherited by all tasks in the included role. See the code below.

```
- name: Task of group_B
  include_role:
    name: role123
    apply:
      tags: group_B
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['group_B']
  tags: group_B
```

Run the play

```
ansible-playbook -t group_B -i ansible_inventory site.yml
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer，but the 2 methods you provided now, the first one, still didn't solve my problem, the second one, a little trouble. In addition, I may not have made it clear before, edit it again, please help me to see it again.